# Customize single-product template

Tags: templates, woocommerce, customization, product

I created my own template named ibtheme, then I copy woocommerce folder from Woocommerce plugin to my template. But when I click on a product on frontpage, I see that it call the template files in plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product, not from ibtheme/woocommerce/templates/single-product/

Please help me to override product page template!

Thanks advance!

Comment: Look I solved my problem by copy single-product folder to ibtheme/woocommerce/ instead ibtheme/woocommerce/templates.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already discovered, you can edit the template files in an upgrade safe way through overrides. Simply copy it into a directory within your theme named /woocommerce, keeping the same file structure.

Example: To overide the price display template, copy: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php` to `wp-content/themes/ibtheme/woocommerce/single-product/price.php`

You can read the full documentation for WooCommerce theming at [Template Structure + overriding templates via a theme](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

I would suggest that only copy/override the specific templates that you plan to modify. I've had to go through every single template to repair a broken theme/site after a major WooCommerce upgrade, so trust me, this will make it easier to upgrade WooCommerce in the future.